# Need help identifying security wiring

Tags: wiring, security

I'm in a new construction home, and the builder is basically blowing us off on questions about the wiring (what's that switch/wire/plate for sorts of things).  My focus for this Q is the security bundle:

I've got 4 22/4 wires I've identified: an entrance keypad, a master bedroom keypad, and a ceiling-mounted motion detector on the main and basement levels.

The only other wire in the bundle is a single Cat.6 labeled (as best I can read the Sharpie chicken-scratch on the cable) "WAP".  Now, in my experience that means "Wireless Access Point" but would it be the same thing in a security context?

Additionally, I have *no idea* where the other end of that Cat.6 cable comes out.  It disappears straight up through the ceiling of the basement and from there, who knows?  I've looked behind every blank plate I can find in the place, and I have accounted for and connected every data port.  Conveniently enough, the security wire is a different color than any of the data cables, so I'd know if I'd found it.  Any ideas how to trace the wire, without busting up the walls, if I can't get ahold of the electrician who installed it?

EDIT: Added several pictures.  Pretty much what you see here is all I get to see of the wiring.

**Here's the security bundle as I found it.**
[image: Here's the wire bundle in the basement.]

**Four 22/4s and a Cat.6, labeled "Basement" "Main Floor KP" "Main Floor Motion" "Master KP" and "WAP."  Most of that's pretty obvious.**
[image: Four 4-element cables and a single Cat.6]

**Mostly they just vanish through here, no further way to trace them from the basement.**
[image: Most disappear through here]

**Apart from the yellow one, the one labeled "Basement," that clearly ends up here.**
[image: The yellow one goes here.]

**This is where the "Main Floor Motion" cable ends up.  Trust me, I'm not climbing back up there to open it up again just now.**
[image: Main floor motion plate here.]

**Here's the entrance keypad wire.**
[image: Entrance keypad wire here.]

**And here's the Master Bedroom keypad wire.**
[image: Master Bedroom keypad wire here.]

That's all I've got to go on, and I could no doubt get something working with just the 4-element wires (and maybe internet monitoring), but I'd like to have some idea how that Cat.6 figures into the scheme if possible.

Comment: The WAP cable probably goes to the attic for a cellular monitoring kit. I don't know why it's called WAP, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Another possibility is that the WAP cable goes to wherever your phone cables enter the house or are terminated. This connects the panel to the phone line.

Answer (score 2):

The trade answer is a toner and probe, it is also the easiest.

An amazon search for ' telephone tracer ' will show a range of products I am talking about.

A toner is the tool that the phone company supplies to their employees that need to find a specific pair of wires in a cable, or inside a wall. Other places use them too.

The tool is art meets science if you are looking for 1 pair of wires in a bundle of 100, but if you are just looking for a cable, they are fairly easy.

This can also be used to find DEAD - NO POWER - outlets/breakers

Comment: There are some which can trace a power wire even when it's live. But "telephone tracer" probanly won't find those.

Comment: @keshlam Yes, on a live circuit a tool like the Klein Tools ET3000 is a nice example. I did become more specific on the issue because the op has said the focus of his question was the Cat 6 wire. ' Circuit breaker tester ' is a useful search for products like that